# How do I add a class to a radio button when using Razor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to add a class called locationFilter to the radio buttons below ?  How do I do this when using Razor ?

```
   @Html.RadioButton("plantFilter", "ALL", (bool)@TempData["ALL"])
   @Html.RadioButton("plantFilter", "IL", (bool)@TempData["MN"]); 
   @Html.RadioButton("plantFilter", "NY", (bool)@TempData["BP"]); 
   @Html.RadioButton("plantFilter", "CA", (bool)@TempData["MT"]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass in an additional parameter (you can see it in IntelliSense with the name *`htmlAttributes`*) with a new anonymous type:

```
new { @class = "yourclass" }
```

Couple of remarks:

- The @ symbol is there because **`class`** is a keyword in C# so the language would think you refer to it. By using the @ you essentially tell the compiler not to understand it as the keyword, but as a normal property name.
- You can add more HTML attributes in this anonymous type, for example if you need to output `title`, you will just add a comma and `title = "something"` inside the anonymous type's building block.

Exact sample for your code:

```
@Html.RadioButton("plantFilter", "IL", (bool)@TempData["MN"], new { @class = "yourclass" });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.RadioButton("plantFilter", "ALL", new { @class = "classname" })
```

RadioButton helper method takes `htmlAttributes` as parameter.You can specify whatever you want inside of it.See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470372%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)